# Anti-Reversing: Unable to patch memory/set breakpoints of process with x64, unusual memory segment

Tags: malware, anti-debugging, protection

I'm working on a sample that contains packing and anti-analysis measures.

Using ScyllaHide plugin for x64dbg currently with all checks enabled (not sure if this would affect anything, I've tried messing with this a bit) I am able to attach the debugger to the process but I am observing some behavior I haven't encountered before.

1. Looking in x64dbgs `Memory Map` tab, the processes main memory segment is layed out differently to what I've seen in the past. Normally it is of type `IMG` and contains the usual `.text`, `.data`, etc memory segments. This samples main segment is of type `MAP` and doesn't contain the normal sections. Is this a technique? What is it called?

There are multiple segments in this sample, here is how they look:

```
Address=00004FF61EC70000
Size=0000000001EE0000
Page Information=malware_sample.exe
Allocation Type=MAP
Current Protection=ER---
Allocation Protection=ER---

Address=00004FF620B50000
Size=0000000000650000
Page Information=malware_sample.exe
Allocation Type=MAP
Current Protection=-RW--
Allocation Protection=-RW--

Address=00004FF6211A0000
Size=000000000013B000
Page Information=malware_sample.exe
Allocation Type=MAP
Current Protection=-R---
Allocation Protection=-R---
```

2. When trying to set breakpoints or patch memory x64dbg fails on the first segment I listed. I am able to place breakpoints on the second segment so my guess is the protection is preventing breakpoints/patching (`Current Protection=ER---`)?
3. When trying to alter the protection of the memory segment in x64dbg using `Set Page Memory Rights` to test if that is the cause of the failure to patch/bps I get an error saying there was a failure to change the memory protection. What can cause this? Is there anti-debugging tricks to prevent changing memory protection?